# How to search for tag + attribute in Chrome devtools element inspector?

Tags: html, search, google-chrome-devtools

I perform a simple search in devtool, but it drops drastically without a reason:

[image]

What's more, if I view the source and do the same search, the number of results of `<link rel` is just 58, not 184. Do you know why?

<sub>Here is the [page](https://xn--qucu-hr5aza.com?utm_source=SE%20%C2%BB%20Stack%20Overflow%20%C2%BB%20search%20results%20in%20devtool&utm_medium=Homepage&utm_campaign=Homepage) if you need to examine.</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For these "complex" queries you'll have to use xPath selectors:

- `//link[@rel]`
- `//link[contains(@rel,'style')]`

or CSS selectors:

- `link[rel]`
- `link[rel*="style"]`

For a trivial CSS selector like `a` use `html a` instead to ensure it doesn't match as literal text.

##### List of supported queries

Devtools uses CDP command [DOM.performSearch](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/DOM/#method-performSearch) and judging by the [implementation](https://source.chromium.org/search?q=symbol:InspectorDOMAgent::performSearch%20file:cc) it tries to match these types of queries:

- `text` - inside #text nodes (like textContent in js)
- `text` - inside tag names
- `text` - inside attribute names
- `text` - inside attribute values
- `<tag` - matching at the start of a tag name
- `</tag` - matching a closing tag
- `tag>` - matching at the end of a tag name
- `<tag>` - matching an entire tag name
- `"text` - matching at the start of an attribute value
- `text"` - matching at the end of an attribute value
- `text` - matching an entire attribute value
- `//a[contains(., 'foo')]` - XPath selector
- `a#foo.class[attr]` - CSS selector

As you can see the literal text matching is limited to the first four types, and it won't find things that span more than one type like `attr="value"` that spans two types.

Comment: what is the advantages of this over literal searching? (Obviously this should have more advantages, but what are they?)

Comment: I guess it's faster. You can suggest a full-text search mode on https://crbug.com.

Comment: Chrome should at least have some kind of tooltip or help text when you search for something like this with literal strings to tell you it's not possible.

Comment: I agree @AmbroseChapel Chrome should definitely have some sort of way to tell devs that using the Find function isn't as straight forward as a normal Find function is. If I want to search for any tag that has the `id` attribute, I should be able to just search for `id=`. Just literal searching should be the default, with options/checkboxes to the side to change it's functionality.